# Update dropdown options based on selected value in jQuery multi-select select2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending an array of objects from the backend to populate the select2 dropdown.

```js
my_array = [
    {"id": "first_issue", "text": "First Issue"},
    {"id": "second_issue", "text": "Second Issue"},
    {"id": "no_issue", "text": "No Issue"}
]

$('#issues').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select Issue Type',
        allowClear: true,
        data: my_array
    });
```

```css
#issues {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns medium-6">
        <label for = "issues" style="text-align: left;" >Issues</label>
        <select class="js-select2" id="issues" name="issues" multiple></select>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

So I am populating the select2 box as above. This select2 is `multi-select` dropdown. Now what I need to do is to conditionally update the `data` parameter of the select2 box so that whenever the option which is an issue i.e., any option other than `no_issue` is selected then the `no_issue` option should not be shown in the dropdown and if it is already selected then it should be removed from the selection and vice versa should happen.
How can I do the same?

Comment: Could you provide a relevant html file to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have added the html of the element.

Comment: if `first_issue` is selected should it be removed also?

Comment: if `first_issue` is selected and then `no_issue` is selected then `first_issue` should be removed. If `first_issue` is selected and `second_issue` is clicked upon then they both should be kept. If `no_issue` is selected and then anyone among the other two is selected then `no_issue` should be removed and the latest selected one should be kept.

Comment: So basically this is a drop-down for filter that I will be doing at the backend. So filtering things that have issues and no issues does not make sense. So I want them to be passed correctly in the request itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please let me know if this achieves what you want. You can test it out with the snippet below.

```js
my_array = [
    {"id": "first_issue", "text": "First Issue"},
    {"id": "second_issue", "text": "Second Issue"},
    {"id": "no_issue", "text": "No Issue"}
]

$('#issues').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select Issue Type',
        allowClear: true,
        data: my_array
    });

$("select").on("select2:select", function(evt) {
    let select = $(this);
    let remove = function(toRemove){
      let values = select.val();
      for (let i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {
        let index = values.indexOf(toRemove[i]);
        if (index >= 0) {
          values.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
      $("select").val(values).change();
    };
    let indexInDOM = $(evt.params.data.element).index();
    if (indexInDOM === 2) {
      remove(["first_issue", "second_issue"]);
    } else {
      remove(["no_issue"]);
    }
});
```

```css
#issues {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns medium-6">
        <label for = "issues" style="text-align: left;" >Issues</label>
        <select class="js-select2" id="issues" name="issues" multiple></select>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```